# Can someone explain to me why after this function is called a becomes 2 instead of 3 or 4?

Tags: c++, function, reference, pass-by-reference

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void f(int &x, int &y)
{
    x = 1;
    x = x + y;
}
int main()
{
    int a = 3;
    f(a, a);
    cout<<a;
    return 0;
}
```

I found this function somewhere and the question was what the value of a is after f(a, a) is called, when a is 3. I thought it should be between 3 and 4 but it somehow gives 2, which I don't understand. Can someone explain why this happens, and how do such functions even work to begin with? Like it's so confusing, since it looks like a is both 3 and 4 after the function.

Comment: Since both `x` and `y` refer to `a`, it is equivalent to `a = 1; a = a + a;` in `main`
.

Comment: It is very unclear why `a` being 2 would suggest that `a` is both 3 and 4, and why you expect the result to be either of them.

Comment: [What is a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use several references to the same object to change it. For example

```
int a;
int &x = a;
int &y = a;

x = 1;
x = x + y;
```

As the both references `x` and `y` point to (are aliases of) the same variable `a` then after this statement

```
x = 1;
```

`a` becomes equal to `1`. And in the next statement

```
x = x + y;
```

in fact you have

```
a = a + a;
```

As a result `a` will be equal to `2`.